# Determine whether the functional series $\sum\frac1{(x+j)^2}$ and $(\sin\frac{x}{j})^j$ are pointwise and/or uniform convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

> Determine whether the following functional series is pointwise and/or uniformly convergent
>
> 1) $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x+j)^2}$ with $(x>0)$
>
> 2)$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} (\sin\frac{x}{j})^j$ with $(x>0)$

Im really unsure where to begin here?

For 1)  $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x+j)^2} < \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{j}$ which is divergent but I cant work out how this would help.

Struggling on what to compare them too! Help please

Comment: Do you know Weierstrass M?

Comment: @zhw. yes, so find a bounded function who's chebyshevs norm is less than the function and then if thats convergent then our function is convergent?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. Take a look at my answer. (Note that saying the function is convergent doesn't make much sense; it's the *series* that either converges or diverges.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: 1) $1/(x+j)^2 \le 1/j^2$ for all $x>0.$

2) Pointwise convergence: For any $x > 0$ there exists $j_0$ such that $0<\sin (x/j_0) <1/2.$ For all $j\ge j_0,$ the absolute value of the $j$th term is therefore $<(1/2)^j.$

Uniform convergence: The series converges uniformly on every $[0,b].$ This follows from the Weierstrass M-test and the idea above. However, the series does not converge uniformly on $[0,\infty).$ To see that, use the fact that if it did converge uniformly on $(0,\infty),$ then

$$\sup_{x\in (0,\infty)}|(\sin(x/j))^j|\to 0 \text { as } j\to \infty.$$

That fails here.

Comment: @ Zhw : You have witten that for any $x > 0$ , there exist $j_0$ such that $0 < \sin( x / j_0) < 1/2$ , so $j_0$ dependent on $x$, so how you can say that $ |\sin (x/j)| < 1/2$ for all $x > 0$ and for all $ j  > j_0$

Comment: I didn't say the last bit; I said for any $x>0$ there exists $j_0;$  $j_0$ depends on $x.$ My hint for 2) is about pointwise convergence

Comment: what will you say abut uniform convergence .

Comment: I added to my answer.

Comment: Firstly thanks for the prompt reply , In the uniform convergence on $[0, \infty)$ , it will be fine , but on $[0,b]$ , if $ b< 1$ , then $|f_n(x)| \leq  (\frac{x}{n}) ^n < x^n < b^n$, then $M_n = b^n$ ,the series $\sum M_n$ is converegent , so $\sum f_n(x)$  converges uniformly , but if $b \geq1$, then what is $M_n$

Comment: Fix any $b>0.$ If $j>2b,$ then for all $x\in [0,b],$ $|[\sin(x/j)]^j| \le (1/2)^j.$ Thus we can take $M_j = 1, 1\le j \le 2b,$ $M_j = (1/2)^j, j> 2b.$